# Copy single cell from range macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have data on Sheet1 which varies in quantity. And I need a macro to loop through all the range if if the cell has a value, then copy it to a specific column on Sheet2. I cannot simply copy the whole range for reasons I won't get into. I need to loop through each cell one by one and paste the value in a specific format on Sheet2.

I have the below code, which gives me

> Error '1004' Method 'Range of Object'_Worksheet' failed.

```
Sub COPY()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, rng As Range, k As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
k = 1
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set rng = Range("B4:D17")
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(i, 1)) Then
ws1.Range(rng.Cells(i, 3)).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `rng` variable is referencing the active worksheet because you did not qualify your `Range` object when you set it.

Comment: @braX I tried updating my set to: Set rng =Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:D17") still same error

Comment: What's going on with `ws1.Range(rng.Cells(i, 3))`? `rng.Cells()` already returns a range object, so why are you placing this into another function that does essentially the same thing?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I need the macro to loop through a range. Then when it comes across a cell with a value. I need it to copy a value in the next column to the next empty cell on another sheet. I think I need to ditch the range.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I used ws1/ws2 initially but when troubleshooting I used the full sheet name.

Comment: Why is your copy destination static? You are looping over a range that reads data row-by-row and overwriting `A1` every time your criteria is met.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs It actually is not static, I just was testing to see if it would paste to the specific cell. Eventually I need it to post to the next empty row.

Comment: Okay, well I will create an answer based off what you have provided, and will let you work out your actual objective later then.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the `rng` object altogether. It would be more necessary in a `For Each` statement, but you are simply looping through rows in your sheet.

Create a simple `For i` statement that just loops the rows you need:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim i As Long
For i = 4 To 17
    If Not IsEmpty(ws1.Cells(i, 2)) Then
        ws1.Cells(i, 4).Copy ws2.Range("A1")
    End If
Next i
```

As I've already pointed out, your copy destination `ws2.Range("A1")` is static, so everytime your criteria is met it continues to overwrite your data here. But you seem to have that handled so I won't assume what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: Take note of my edit to this answer of `ws1.Cells(i, 1)` and `ws1.Cells.(i, 4)` - you were basing 1, 3 in your code as the first column relative to the `rng` object, and I've corrected my answer to being the real column numbers you are needing.